# Как осуществить правильную проверку выбора кнопки JRadioButton?

Tags: java, swing

Вот кусок текста программы:

```
public class ViewFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public JRadioButton deptRadioButton;
    public JRadioButton empRadioButton;
    public JRadioButton salRadioButton;
    public String direct;
    public ViewFrame() {
        setTitle("AppDirectory");
        setSize(700, 600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel dbTablePanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        DataBaseTableModel dbtm = new DataBaseTableModel("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl",
            "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver", "SCOTT", "TIGER");
        JTable dbTable = new JTable(dbtm);
        System.out.println(deptRadioButton.isSelected());

        /*if(deptRadioButton.isSelected()){
            direct = "SELECT * FROM SCOTT.DEPT";
        }
        else if(empRadioButton.isSelected()){
            direct = "SELECT * FROM SCOTT.EMP";
        }
        else {
            direct = "SELECT * FROM SCOTT.SALGRADE";
        }*/

        dbtm.executeQuery(direct);

        JScrollPane dbTableScrollPane = new JScrollPane(dbTable);
        dbTableScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(550, 250));

        dbTablePanel.add(dbTableScrollPane, new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 3, 1, 2,
        1, GridBagConstraints.NORTH, GridBagConstraints.BOTH,
        new Insets(1, 1, 1, 1), 0, 0));

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        JButton addButton = new JButton("Ввод");
        addButton.setToolTipText("Ввести новые данные в таблицу");
        JButton editButton = new JButton("Редактировать");
        editButton.setToolTipText("Редактировать существующую запись");
        JButton deleteButton = new JButton("Удалить");
        deleteButton.setToolTipText("Удалить данные из таблицы");
        JButton dropButton = new JButton("Очистить");
        dropButton.setToolTipText("Очистить таблицу");
        dropButton.setBackground(Color.RED);
        dropButton.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

        buttonPanel.add(addButton, new GridBagConstraints(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        GridBagConstraints.NORTH, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,
        new Insets(1, 1, 1, 1), 0, 0));
        buttonPanel.add(editButton, new GridBagConstraints(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        GridBagConstraints.NORTH, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,
        new Insets(1, 1, 1, 1), 0, 0));
        buttonPanel.add(deleteButton, new GridBagConstraints(2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        GridBagConstraints.NORTH, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,
        new Insets(1, 1, 1, 1), 0, 0));
        buttonPanel.add(dropButton, new GridBagConstraints(3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        GridBagConstraints.NORTH, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,
        new Insets(1, 1, 1, 1), 0, 0));

        add(dbTablePanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        setVisible(false);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}
```

я пробовал и `isChecked()`, и `isSelected()`, и такую форму:

```
true.isSelected().equals(deptRadioButton);
```

и такую:

```
deptRadioButton.isSelected().equals(true);
```

Comment: А что возвращает `deptRadioButton.isSelected()`, если вывести прямо на экран?

Comment: System.out.println(deptRadioButton.isSelected()); возвращает ошибку
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Если описать ситуацию подробней, то есть 3 радио кнопки(deptRadioButton, empRadioButton, salRadioButton) и кнопка выбора с именем selectButton. После выбора радио кнопки необходимо вместо в переменную query записывать одно из значений("SELECT * FROM SCOTT.DEPT", "SELECT * FROM SCOTT.EMP", "SELECT * FROM SCOTT.SALGRADE"), которое в свою очередь посылает запрос в БД Oracle и возвращает в новом фрейме в Jtable таблицу  в зависимости от запроса(DEPT, EMP, SALGRADE).

Comment: вроде написал такой простой цикл проверяющий какая радио кнопка выбрана, но почему то не работает

Comment: Опубликуйте в теле вопроса объявление радиокнопок, пожалуйста. Ваша ошибка указывает на то, что переменная не инициализирована.

Comment: в общем залил весь фрейм, извините за трудность читабельности с самого начала

Comment: дело в том что эти кнопки наследуются из другого фрейма

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException` в этом контексте возникает из-за того, что объект класса не инициализирован. 
Вообще жизненный цикл объектов в Java вкратце состоит из следующих пунктов:

1. Объявление объекта
2. Инициализация объекта(Вызов конструктора. Тут объект становится доступным для использования)
3. Выход из пределов доступности объекта (Тут объект становится доступным для сборщика мусора)

В этой строке вы объявили объект:

```
public JRadioButton deptRadioButton;
```

Но не инициализировали его. Поэтому получаете `NullPointerException`, и поэтому не можете обратиться к методу объекта. Вам нужно инициализировать объект, вызвав один из конструкторов:

```
public JRadioButton deptRadioButton = new JRadioButton();
```

К слову, этих конструкторов у `JRadioButton` несколько. Подробнее о них можете [прочитать в официальной документации](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JRadioButton.html)

Comment: ответ правильный ошибка перестала появляться, однако цикл срабатывает постоянно на else

Comment: @СашаСеменец, какой цикл? В теле вопроса нет цикла.

Comment: за комментированный. Он должен срабатывать

Comment: У вас нет закомментированного цикла в коде, что я вижу. Там есть `if`.

Comment: Что возвращает `deptRadioButton.isSelected()`, если выводить на экран?

Comment: в общем цикл: раз комментирован, строка System.out.println(deptRadioButton.isSelected()); удалена

Comment: в том то и суть цикла, что при проверке включена ли радио кнопка строка direct принимает определенное значение

Comment: Напишите, пожалуйста, результат вывода этой строки `System.out.println(deptRadioButton.isSelected()); `

Comment: выводит false....

Comment: А вы кнопку выделяете? Кликаете на неё?

Comment: конечно выделяю, кликаю на неё. и для неё написан ActionListener

Comment: Проинициализируйте одну из кнопок следующим образом:
`JRadioButton deptRadioButton = new JRadioButton("Dept", true);`

Comment: так работает, но не смотря на то что я выбираю другие значения программа настойчиво выводит бд при активации deptRadioButton

Comment: две остальных проверил по аналогии с JRadioButton deptRadioButton = new JRadioButton("Dept", true);
JRadioButton empRadioButton = new JRadioButton("Emp", true);
JRadioButton salRadioButton = new JRadioButton("Salgrade", true); - соответственно.

Comment: Мне кажется, что вы проверяете нажатие не там, где нужно. Выведите проверку нажатия в отдельный метод. В ActionListener радиокнопок вызовите этот метод.

Comment: спасибо большое, выручили)